# IIS Rewrite Rule Redirect HTTP to HTTPS causes multiple RedirectURL querystring

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

We're using this rule to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This works fine but when a user has bookmarked a URL like this:

```
h t t p://www.mysite.com/myapp/login.aspx?ReturlURL=/someurl
```

It redirect them to HTTPS as expected but with 2 ReturnURL querystring which causes a 404 error when they login:

```
h t t p s://www.mysite.com/myapp/login.aspx?ReturnURL=/someurl&ReturnURL=/someurl
```

How to handle this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't allow URL so I have to put spaces in http/https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your action to:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
```

Note the `appendQueryString="false"` attribute :)

Comment: I have the same problem but the solution posted here doesn't work... Here's my rule:
`<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTP To HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>`